# Performance of Streams in Java 8 in high response web Applications

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am using JSP/Serverlets for my upcoming web application project. It is high traffic concurrent users web site. There has been many discussion about performance issues of Java 8 and especially in Streams.

Anyone having specific knowledge about performance of streams and whether its advisable to use in High traffic Web Applications so as to not compromise on latency and response time ?

Answer (score 1):

As a general statement, outside of Java 8 Streams, it is pretty much impossible to answer your question as stated because it depends.

If you've got a method that is called hundreds of times per second then you would need to be very careful about performance.  You'd want to tune it the best you could.  Conversely, if you've got a method that gets called once a day then you likely wouldn't spend too much time optimizing it.

Streams are a useful tool when used correctly and they are easy to abuse.  I've seen developers who thought it was a great idea to read an entire database table and use filtering with streams to effectively do a SQL "where" clause.  That's a bad design but it honestly wouldn't be seen in the once-a-day method call.

Don't try to make these blanket "this is good or this is bad" statements.  Do a good design and use the tools where they are appropriate.  Optimize the parts of your application that need it but don't do pre-mature optimizations - you'll never finish the project.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using Mongodb as backend. And most of the data processes in streams is not database related but related to collection data received from form data. As from your insights I don't think there should be much overhead there.